# Find out when the last use of variable was removed from the git repo

Tags: git, version-control, grep, git-grep

I have an unused variable in my code, and I wonder how things got to be this way.  Can I use git grep (or something else) to find out easily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git log -Svarname
```

where `varname` is the name your variable.

See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#git-log--Sltstringgt:

Look for differences that change the number of occurrences of the specified string (i.e. addition/deletion) in a file.

Comment: That was way easier than I had any right to expect.  Thank you.